# Communication of Hadoop Cluster and google like interface.How?

Tags: spring, hadoop

My boss told me to setup a google like interface that you enter a keyword and you press the button and it returns the result to the screen. When you press the button, hadoop cluster will work behind and return the result. I already setup a hadoop cluster and make wordcount work but I have no idea how this google like interface will communicate with hadoop cluster and make suitable .jar and then return the result. I have experience with Spring Framework but if you have some other suggestions I am open to them. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: This question could use some better detail and formatting.

Comment: Hi Travaglini. What I want to learn is how will I communicate with hadoop cluster from a text box? I will write a keyword in the textbox and when I click on search, it will generate a hadoop command using this keyword and this will be sent to hadoop for processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your boss has made a big mistake if he has asked you to do it through Hadoop. Hadoop is not at all suitable for real time stuff like search. When you run a Hadoop job it incurs some initial delay as a lot of things happen under the hood before Hadoop actually starts the processing. And obviously you don't want your users to wait for several seconds(or maybe more, depends on your data) before they get the results. So, if you are planning to launch a Hadoop job when a user submits a search query and expecting the search results within a fraction of time, you are on the wrong track.

But, you can use Hadoop beforehand in order to make your app better. For example, you can use MapReduce jobs to index your data faster and get it ready to be served when somebody wants to search something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tariq. But I know that some search engines utilize Hadoop under the hood like http://ara.com.tr/ Do you know exactly what for Hadoop is used in those search engines? Only for indexing data?